# MATLAB - How can I crop some part of an image from .fig file and save it as .mat?

Tags: image, matlab, crop

I have a .fig file. I put the *32x32* square on the image where I want. I write this code:

```
h = imrect(gca,[1 1 32 32]);
```

However I don't crop *32x32* part of the image. How to crop and save as .mat from .fig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *getPosition* property of [imrect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) object. If you are working with a *.fig* file, you can initially use the [getimage](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getimage.html) function to get the image from the Image handle.

```
%% If you are working with a image file.    
%Sample image.
%I = imread('cameraman.tif');

%Display image.
%imshow(I);

%% If you are working with a .fig file. 
%In the following example, yourfile.fig is cameraman.tif previously saved as a .fig file.
I = open('yourfile.fig')
I = getimage(I); 

%Draw rectangle.
h = imrect(gca,[100 30 40 32]);

%Crop rectangle.
J=imcrop(I,h.getPosition);

%Show rectangle.
imshow(J);

%Save as .mat file
save('mymatfile.mat','J');
```

---

**Initial image:**

[image]

**imrect object added**:

[image]

**Cropped element**:

[image]